# How to solve this boolean algebra problem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra

Given two expressions: $$A\bar{D}+A\bar{C}D +A\bar{B}C + ABCD = Y$$ and $$BD+A\bar{C}D=Z$$ is there a way to simplify this using the rules for Boolean Algebra? I tried different combinations, but if I factor out AC or D such as $$D(\bar{A}+A\bar{C})+AC(\bar{B}+BD)$$I am left with a problem that I cannot simplify further since I get multiple terms, the same goes for the second equation e.g. $$D(B+A\bar{C})$$ but then I am stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your goal, exactly?

Comment: @AlexKruckman My goal is to reduce this circuit to the simplest possible circuit i.e. to simplify the top and bottom equation to lowest terms. I believe the bottom equation cannot be simplified further;however, the top one can, I just cannot find a way how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equation is equivalent to $A = Y$:
$$\begin{align}
A\bar{D}+A\bar{C}D + A\bar{B}C + ABCD &= A(\bar{D}+\bar{C}D + C(\bar{B} + BD))\\
&= A(\bar{D} + \bar{C}D + C(\bar{B}(\bar{D}+D) + BD))\\
&= A(\bar{D} + \bar{C}D + C(\bar{B}\bar{D} + (\bar{B} + B)D))\\
&= A(\bar{D} + \bar{C}D + C\bar{B}\bar{D} + CD)\\
&= A(\bar{D} + (\bar{C}+C)D + C\bar{B}\bar{D})\\
&= A(\bar{D} + D + C\bar{B}\bar{D})\\
&= A(\top + C\bar{B}\bar{D})\\
&= A\top\\
&= A
\end{align}$$